# Question in the appendixes A of O'Neill book

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

I'm reading appendixes A of O'Neill's book, "Semi-riemannian geometry" and I don't understand a something.
[image]

I don't understand at the last theorem, how we construct a universal cover for $M$ and why is that (if it is) a manifold.

Comment: The construction is not described in the paragraph you quote. He only claims that it is legit to discuss *the* simply connected covering, as opposed to *a* simply connected covering.

Comment: Yeah, sure but i put the whole paragraph to show the lack of explanation and as a reference for someone who might use this as a tool for the proof. So my question becomes where can I find a proof for this theorem?

Comment: If you’re willing to invest some time it’s in chapter 3 of Peter May book https://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/CONCISE/ConciseRevised.pdf